# How can I iterate through an array of objects and call methods of the objects?

Tags: java, arrays, methods

Here is the code I have. I would like it to be less clunky if possible. Soccer and Basketball are subclasses of Player. arr[i].methodName() only works for methods in the superclass and I would like for methods in the subclass to be called in the same way if possible.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
    public class PlayerClient {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Soccer s1 = new Soccer("Robert", 12, 200000, 3, 1, 17);
            Soccer s2 = new Soccer("Carrot", 7, 400000, 1, 4, 35);
            Basketball b1 = new Basketball("Jeremy", 37, 300000, 70, 6.3);
            Basketball b2 = new Basketball("Lebron", 65, 1000000, 130, 9.0);
            Player[] arr = {s1, s2, b1, b2};
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                System.out.println("\n\n" + arr[i].getName());
                System.out.println(arr[i].getNumber());
                System.out.println(arr[i].getSalary());
                if (arr[i].equals(s1)) {
                    System.out.println(s1.getYellowFlags());
                    System.out.println(s1.getRedFlags());
                    System.out.println(s1.getGoalsScored() + "\n\n");
                } else if (arr[i].equals(s2)) {
                    System.out.println(s2.getYellowFlags());
                    System.out.println(s2.getRedFlags());
                    System.out.println(s2.getGoalsScored() + "\n\n");
                } else if (arr[i].equals(b1)) {
                    System.out.println(b1.getjumpHeight());
                    System.out.println(b1.getjumpHeight() + "\n\n");
                } else if (arr[i].equals(b2)) {
                    System.out.println(b2.getjumpHeight());
                    System.out.println(b2.getBasketsScored() + "\n\n");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is the Template Method Design pattern:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/template_pattern.htm

Define abstract methods on the base class, to enforce that they are implemented in child classes. Then you can call the method on the base type while it may have different implementations for each child class.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public class PlayerClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Soccer s1 = new Soccer("Robert", 12, 200000, 3, 1, 17);
        Soccer s2 = new Soccer("Carrot", 7, 400000, 1, 4, 35);
        Basketball b1 = new Basketball("Jeremy", 37, 300000, 70, 6.3);
        Basketball b2 = new Basketball("Lebron", 65, 1000000, 130, 9.0);
        Player[] arr = {s1, s2, b1, b2};
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("\n\n" + arr[i].getName());
            System.out.println(arr[i].getNumber());
            System.out.println(arr[i].getSalary());
            System.out.println(arr[i].printScore());
        }
    }
}


public abstract class Player {
    abstract void printScore();

    // existing code
}

public class Soccer extends Player {
    @Override        
    void printScore() {
        System.out.println(getYellowFlags());
        System.out.println(getRedFlags());
        System.out.println(getGoalsScored() + "\n\n");
    }

    // existing methods
}

public class Basketball extends Player {
    @Override        
    void printScore() {
        System.out.println(getjumpHeight());
        System.out.println(getjumpHeight() + "\n\n");
    }

    // existing methods
}
```